# Why ShellExecute can not find a file?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

as comming from a *nix world I'm very confused with Windows behaviour and probably its security system.

I'm simply trying to execute an external program within my app. I've found the WinAPI function ShellExecute which works as expected *except when launching **some** programs placed in %windir%\System32* subdirectory.

- execution of ping.exe succeeds

  ```
  ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "c:\\Windows\\System32\\ping.exe', NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW) );
  // ^^^ OK, retcode == 42
  ```
- execution of java.exe fails

  ```
  ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "c:\\Windows\\System32\\java.exe', NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW) );
  // ^^^ ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, retcode == 2
  ```

It's very strange because **java.exe does exist in System32**, has read/execute permissions for Users group and can be invoked from cmd.

```
C:\>dir /q c:\Windows\System32\java.exe
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 56E3-0868

 Directory of c:\Windows\System32

11.01.2012  23:40           172 320 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    java.exe
               1 File(s)        172 320 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  226 127 564 800 bytes free

C:\>cacls c:\Windows\System32\java.exe
c:\Windows\System32\java.exe NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:F
                             BUILTIN\Administrators:F
                             BUILTIN\Users:R
```

What am I missing here ?

OS is Windows 7 Home edition.

**Update:** If I copy c:\Windows\Sytem32\calc.exe to c:\Windows\Sytem32\calc2.exe, *ShellExecute can run original calc.exe but fails with calc2.exe although files are identical !!* The only difference are additional permissions for TrustedInstaller group which calc2.exe and also java.exe are missing.  A coincidence ?

Comment: Perhaps a matter of dependencies? Maybe Java depends on a DLL which isn't in the search path?

Comment: No, java.exe is not even launched. It's ShellExecute return value of 2 which signalizes executable was not found.

Comment: What happens when you run `c:\Windows\System32\java.exe` from the command line (using the same user/environment as does `ShellExecute`)?

Comment: C:\>c:\Windows\System32\java.exe
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>  ...  etc

Comment: Your problems don't start and stop with the `ShellExecute` function. The other serious issue is that you're hard-coding paths. I'd like to assume this is only for testing purposes, but I've seen so many people who don't know better that I can't just assume that. My system directory is not located at `C:\Windows\System32` and even if you assume a "standard" installation, you're going to run into trouble on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Also, unless you're compiling in non-Unicode mode (which you shouldn't be, Windows applications have been fully Unicode for nearly 20 years), you should be prefixing your string literals with an `L`.

Comment: Is your program running with administrator rights? Do you have UAC on?

Comment: Does your program work correctly if you put it under **c:\\Program Files\?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you running a 64 bit operating system?

If so, `C:\Windows\System32` will contain 64 bit binaries while `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` will contain 32 bit binaries (yes, it really is that way around). For backwards compatibility reasons, when running 32 bit processes, Windows redirects access to `C:\Windows\System32` to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

So if you're using a 32 bit process to look at `C:\Windows\System32`, you're actually seeing what's in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

You can call the [`Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743.aspx) function to disable this behavior. Do note the warning in the documentation and consider carefully whether it applies to your case:

> **Note:**  The `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection` function affects all file operations performed by the current thread, which can have unintended consequences if file system redirection is disabled for any length of time. For example, DLL loading depends on file system redirection, so disabling file system redirection will cause DLL loading to fail. Also, many feature implementations use delayed loading and will fail while redirection is disabled. The failure state of the initial delay-load operation is persisted, so any subsequent use of the delay-load function will fail even after file system redirection is re-enabled. To avoid these problems, disable file system redirection immediately before calls to specific file I/O functions (such as `CreateFile`) that must not be redirected, and re-enable file system redirection immediately afterward using [`Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365745.aspx).

Comment: *uck ! That's the right answer. Just curious what programmer can do to execute external apps from System32 if Windows ignores & replaces even full path specification ? This misconception is integrated into system due to some older malfunction programs ? *uck, *uck :(

Comment: Yup.  You might want to mention Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()

Comment: Yes, it's because programmers in the past hard-coded paths. *hint, hint*.

Comment: Cody Gray> Mea culpa ;) But I just tested some functionality and final code would be correct written, believe me.

Comment: Hans Passant> Good to know about Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection function. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't adding a manifest file also disable all kind of redirections?

Answer (score 1):

Use [ProcessMonitor](http://live.sysinternals.com/Procmon.exe) to figure out which files are being accessed and what file operation fails and why.

Answer (score 0):

Check the environment settings, e.g. "PATH". Windows keeps a separate environment for the system and for users.  It might be that the DLL's needed by Java.exe are only listed in one environment and when you are running it through ShellExecute it is using the other environment.

Comment: It is probably not about environment settings. Please see question update with attempt to run identical files of MS Calc.