# Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection fileExits

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010

a file is located in C:\program files (x86)\my app\myexe.exe

1. FileExists('C:\program files (x86)\my app\myexe.exe')  returns **true**;
2. FileExists('C:\program files\my app\myexe.exe')  returns **false**;
   **in both cases**, if I use Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection or not.

Why ? Thanks

Comment: Can you show how you're uysing the Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection part and when?

Comment: Does Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection has an impact on path starting with "C:\program files" ?

Comment: The program files folders are not redirected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

File system redirection is only there for the `%windir%\system32` directory. The [description of the File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems to make this obvious.

Note the comment in the page

> Applications should use the `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` function to determine the %ProgramFiles% directory name.

**Edit** Turns out that the FOLDERID_ProgramFilesx64 does not work on 32bit applications running on 64bit windows. In this case, you can use the environment variable `%ProgramW6432%` instead. Note that this variable is **only** available on Windows 7 and later for 32bit applications.

The following delphi snippet allows accessing the variable:

```
function GetEnvironmentString(aString : string) : string;
var
  dest : string;
  retSize : integer;
begin
  SetLength(dest, MAX_PATH);
  retSize := ExpandEnvironmentStrings(pchar(aString), pchar(dest), MAX_PATH);
  if retSize > 0 then
      SetLength(dest, retSize - 1);
  result := dest;
end;
```

Called as:

```
GetEnvironmentString('%ProgramW6432%');
```

IF you're on a 64bit version of windows, then a 32bit application cannot use `FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64` to explicitly get the 64bit location of `Program Files`, but can use the environment variable expansion instead. On a 32bit version of windows, this location is invalid, and will not get you a value. You need to check the bitness of the system before attempting to access this variable.

You can use the function [IsWow64Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine this. The [following snippet](http://www.delphidabbler.com/codesnip?action=named&routines=IsWow64&showsrc=1) should allow you to check this:

```
function IsWow64: Boolean;
type
  TIsWow64Process = function(Handle: Windows.THandle; var Res: Windows.BOOL): Windows.BOOL; stdcall;
var
  IsWow64Result: Windows.BOOL;
  IsWow64Process: TIsWow64Process;
begin
  // Try to load required function from kernel32
  IsWow64Process := Windows.GetProcAddress(Windows.GetModuleHandle('kernel32.dll'), 'IsWow64Process');
  if Assigned(IsWow64Process) then
  begin
    // Function is implemented: call it
    if not IsWow64Process(Windows.GetCurrentProcess, IsWow64Result) then
      raise SysUtils.Exception.Create('IsWow64: bad process handle');
    // Return result of function
    Result := IsWow64Result;
  end
  else
    // Function not implemented: can't be running on Wow64
    Result := False;
end;
```

**In summary**: `FOLDERID_ProgramFiles` gives you the 32/64 bit variant when accessed from a 32/64 bit program, `FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64` gives you the 64bit version explicitly on a 64-bit application, and `FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX86` gives you the 32bit variant explicitly. You can use the environment variable expansion to get the 64bit value on a 32bit application

Comment: No other path concerned then ?

Comment: As stated in the page, In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access %windir%\System32, the access is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64. Access to %windir%\lastgood\system32 is redirected to %windir%\lastgood\SysWOW64. Access to %windir%\regedit.exe is redirected to %windir%\SysWOW64\regedit.exe. There are some explicit excpetions, and they are called out on the page as well.

Comment: As showed here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426708/accessing-icons-in-a-64bit-exe-with-a-32bit-program it seems that a 32bit app will resolve shortcuts that contain %Programfiles% to the x86 directory...

Comment: Caused by explorer being a 32bit application. The document at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463051.aspx contains a lot of useful hints and details in relation to appropriate variable use

Comment: `FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64` **is not** available to 32-bit apps running under WOW64.  This is [documented by MSDN](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/F/7/AF7777E5-7DCD-4800-8A0A-B18336565F5B/wow64_bestprac.docx): "Some variables work only if the process is 64-bit. For example, FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64 does not work for 32-bit callers". However, a 32-bit process can use the `%ProgramW6432%` environment variable instead, at least on Windows 7 and later.

Comment: self contradictory document - the table in the document implies it will work, while a sample program shows that it doesn't